# MySQL - how can this query be optimized?

Tags: mysql, query-optimization

I am trying to generate a list of all user's tags with a count of the number of tasks they are associated with...

```
SELECT * FROM 
 ( SELECT tags.tag_id, tags.tag_text, tags.type, task_tags.tag_id AS task_tag_id,
   count(task_tags.tag_id) AS TaskCount 
   FROM tags 
   LEFT JOIN task_tags ON tags.tag_id = task_tags.tag_id 
   WHERE tags.user_id = 2 
   GROUP BY tag_id ) 
AS temp_table ORDER BY tag_text
```

Here are the EXPLAIN results:

```
id  select_type     table   type    possible_keys   key     key_len     ref     rows    Extra   
1   PRIMARY     <derived2>  ALL     NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    13  Using filesort
2   DERIVED     tags    ref     user_tag    user_tag    4   const   13  Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort
2   DERIVED     task_tags   ref     tag_id  tag_id  4   taskmandb1234.tags.tag_id   1   Using index
```

Comment: Please run `SHOW CREATE TABLE <tablename>` for each of your tables in the query and include it in your question. I and many other Stack Overflow users won't even look at your query optimization question until you do this.

Comment: @BillKarwin - Thanks for adding the extra tag.  There are so many mysql-tagged Questions, that I only look at those with a second tag of a handful of tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how it should look like when you don't select the column `task_tags.tag_id` because you don't group or aggregate it.

```
   SELECT tags.tag_id, tags.tag_text, tags.type, 
          count(task_tags.tag_id) AS TaskCount 
   FROM tags 
   LEFT JOIN task_tags ON tags.tag_id = task_tags.tag_id 
   WHERE tags.user_id = 2 
   GROUP BY tags.tag_id, tags.tag_text, tags.type
   ORDER BY tags.tag_text
```

Besides that make sure you have keys on `tags.user_id` and `tags.tag_text`.

Comment: I do have keys on tags.user_id and tags.tag_text.  This is definitely improved.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably faster than using the `LEFT JOIN`, which suffers from the "explode-implode syndrome".

```
SELECT  tag_id, tag_text, type,
        ( SELECT COUNT(*) FROM task_tags
                     WHERE tag_id = t.tag_id ) AS TaskCount
    FROM  tags AS t
    WHERE  user_id = 2
    ORDER BY  tag_text
```

It needs indexes:

```
tags:  INDEX(user_id, tag_text, type, tag_id)
task_tags:  INDEX(tag_id)
```

Both indexes are "covering" and handle the `WHERE` and `ORDER BY`.

If, however, `tag_text` is a `TEXT` column, then the `tags` index I suggest will not work.  Let's see `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.

Note:  `COUNT(x)` checks `x` for being not-NULL.  I think I have avoided the need for such a check; hence `COUNT(*)` is 'better'.